# Check user authentification in Open Social gadget from backend

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, vert.x, opensocial

I am writing a gadget for an OpenSocial site (www.graasp.eu).
Inside my gadget I open a connection to a server. To be exact a vert.x event bus opens a connection to my Vert.x backend with the help of sockJS.

Now I want to somehow check, if the user, who opens the connection, is successfully logged in to the OpenSocial site to permit the connection.

Any idea how I can do that?
Can I access the OAuth token, send it to my server and ask the OpenSocial site if this token is valid?

Answer (score 0):

For those who has the same problems. You can use signed requests:
https://opensocial.atlassian.net/wiki/display/OSREF/Introduction+To+Signed+Requests

The gadget can send this signed request over an open social server like shindig to your custom server. Then you have to validate the request:
https://opensocial.atlassian.net/wiki/display/OSREF/Validating+Signed+Requests

If the request is valid, you have to store the user id and a session key, which you have to generate. Then send the generated session key back.
The gadget now opens a sockJS connection to your server and authentificats himself by the user id and the session key he received.